# Problem in docker installation

Tags: 18.04, docker

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and recently installed Docker using the Xenial build by following the instructions found here. I haven't encountered any problems creating containers, ensuring they restart automatically, etc.

However when i type docker version:

```
Docker version 0.20180713.170521-2ec1ced, build 2ec1ced

The docker version is not known.
```

And , now every time I run apt-get update I receive the following error message:

```
Err:14 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu stable Release                                                           
  404  Not Found [IP : 52.85.242.38 443]
Atteint:15 https://downloads.opennebula.org/repo/5.5/Ubuntu/18.04 stable Release                                        
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait                          
E: Le dépôt https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu stable Release n'a pas de fichier Release.
N: Les mises à jour depuis un tel dépôt ne peuvent s'effectuer de manière sécurisée, et sont donc désactivées par défaut
N: Voir les pages de manuel d'apt-secure(8) pour la création des dépôts et les détails de configuration d'un utilisateur.
N: Le fichier configuré « stable/binary-x86_64/Packages » ne sera pas pris en compte car le dépôt « https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic InRelease » ne supporte pas l'architecture « x86_64 »
```

I have tried to remedy the problem by following the advice found here and cannot seem to solve this problem.

Has anyone encountered this before and fixed it? If so, what is needed to resolve this?

Comment: xenial build? why not the bionic build?

Comment: @damadam, i used xenial build then i change to bionic build following this link  https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/290  but i still having the problem

Comment: which docker packages do you have installed?
dpkg -l | grep docker

Comment: @redseven,   ii  docker-ce                                  1:0.20180713.170521-2ec1ced-0~ubuntu    amd64        Docker: the open-source application container engine

Answer (score 5):

I had same problem. I fix it with removing every "docker" line in configuration file,

```
/etc/apt/sources.list
```

and then run this.

```
sudo apt update
```

After this, I ran command again,

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic stable"
```

and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Use the right repo, put this to your `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list` file:

```
deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic stable
```

If that is the first time you use this repo you also need to import the key:

```
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
```

be sure you don't have the old `docker-engine` or other outdated docker package.
Looks like you have issue with the package version as well, so better to remove your current package:

```
sudo apt purge docker-ce
```

and reinstall it from the repo:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install docker-ce
```

More info in the official guide: https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/

Comment: I still having same errors with this solutions

Comment: did the "apt install docker-ce" update your package? What is the version now?

Comment: The "apt install docker-ce" gives this message   ""docker-ce is already the newest version (1:0.20180713.170521-2ec1ced-0~ubuntu)""

Comment: I've updated the description how to remove your package first...

Answer (score 1):

1. inside `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`, I fixed the problem by commented `docker.list`
2. `cat docker.list` -> `#deb http://get.docker.io/ubuntu docker main`

**Note**: If the problem is still there, maybe try to comment other files related to docker.

- For instance, nvidia-docker.list contains `deb https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/ubuntu18.04/amd64 /`. However, I fixed the error by just commented on the `docker.list`

[The files inside `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpEqu.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue - but for me, I had set my apt up to use the nightly repos as docker-ce wasn't available in stable on Ubuntu 18 initially. It seems that now a 0.2 version has appeared in that repos. I changed my repos back to "stable", did a apt remove docker-ce and then apt install docker-ce and this sorted it for me.

Comment: Actually  i use an edge repo , in my       /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list   file i write :::    "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic edge"    And it seems work fine in the creation of containers and images but when i run apt-get update/upgrade I receive the error  described above.

Answer (score 0):

I use Linux Mint 19 Cinnamon. (Tara(!)).

The thing that worked for me was to change "tara" with "bionic" for the repository link:

deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu **bionic** stable

I tried to comment on the answer that was already given by redseven but I don't have enough reputation to do so, hence the separate answer.